# Transpose Table columns into another Table Rows

Tags: sql-server, transpose

I have a SQL Server table called `Store_PartsQTY_Migration` with the following Fields :

| part_no |
| --- |
| Hand0 |
| Hand1 |
| Hand2 |
| Hand3 |
| Hand4 |
| Hand5 |
| Hand6 |
| Hand7 |
| Hand8 |
| Hand9 |
| Hand10 |
| Hand11 |
| Hand12 |

and I want to fill a new table named StorePartsQTY_NewMigration  with the following Fields :

part_no
Hand
Quantity
knowing that Hand0 column is the Hand number 0 and the value of it is the Quantity so how can I transpose columns to rows (part_no is a primary key) ?

```
INSERT INTO StorePartsQTY_NewMigration  (part_no Hand Quantity)
SELECT part_no Hand Quantity
FROM (
SELECT part_no,Hand0,Hand1,Hand2,Hand3,Hand4,Hand5,Hand6,Hand7, Hand8,Hand9,Hand10,Hand11,Hand12
FROM Store_PartsQTY_Migration
) p
UNPIVOT (
Quantity FOR Hand IN (Hand0,Hand1,Hand2,Hand3,Hand4,Hand5,Hand6 ,Hand7,Hand8,Hand9,Hand10,Hand11,Hand12)
) AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Does what you have not work? Looks like you are missing commas in various places though

Comment: no dear i put commas but it disappear here

Comment: Please don't remove the formatting other users have done for you.

Comment: The query you've given us is still invalid. `part_no Hand Quantity` isn't a valid for the columns in an `INSERT` and you are trying to give your column `part_no` *two* aliases in your `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this?

https://dbfiddle.uk/jpW4S6Ob

That is, the UNPIVOT command would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO StorePartsQTY_NewMigration (part_no, Hand, Quantity)
SELECT part_no, CAST(REPLACE(Hand, 'Hand', '') AS INT) AS Hand, Quantity
FROM (
  SELECT part_no, Hand0, Hand1, Hand2, Hand3, Hand4, Hand5, Hand6, Hand7, Hand8, Hand9, Hand10, Hand11, Hand12
  FROM Store_PartsQTY_Migration
) p
UNPIVOT (
  Quantity FOR Hand IN (Hand0, Hand1, Hand2, Hand3, Hand4, Hand5, Hand6, Hand7, Hand8, Hand9, Hand10, Hand11, Hand12)
) AS unpivoted;
```

Comment: Thank you dear for your response , 
please note that 
Store_PartsQTY_Migration.Hand0 = 5 
means that hand number 0 has qty of 5

and I should reflect this in the second table as the following
Part_No= Part_No
Hand=0
QTY = 5
Store_PartsQTY_Migration.Hand3 = 7 
means that hand number 3 has qty of 7

and I should reflect this in the second table as the following
Part_No= Part_No
Hand=3
QTY = 7

can you please advise how to solve this ? 
Thank you for your time and efforts helping me dear

Answer (score 0):

After a log time of search the solution was as the following :

```
    INSERT INTO StorePartsQTY_NewMigration (part_no, Hand, QTY)
    SELECT part_no, CAST(REPLACE(col, 'Hand', '') AS int) AS Hand, value AS QTY
    FROM Store_PartsQTY_Migration
    UNPIVOT
    (
      value FOR col IN (Hand0, Hand1, Hand2, Hand3,
                       Hand4, Hand5, Hand6, Hand7, 
                       Hand8, Hand9, Hand10, Hand11, Hand12
                      )
    ) AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Looks pretty much the same as that query in my fiddle...?